# Bottom Bar + Drawer Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, navigation-drawer, bottomnavigationview

**Bottom Bar + Drawer Navigation . If I want to implement these both together, which should implement first ?**

1. Bottom bar then Drawer navigator OR
2. Drawer then Bottom Navigator

Anyone please answer with proper explanation....
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first should be drawer ideally and then tabs.

But it all depends upon your business requirement.

https://snack.expo.dev/@gaurav1995/nesting-navigators-%7C-react-navigation

check the above snack, have implemented.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
        title="Go to notifications"
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
        title="Go to notifications"
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function PlaceHome({navigation}){
  return(
    <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown:false}} >
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}

function NotificationsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Go back home" />
    </View>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator useLegacyImplementation initialRouteName="DummyHome">
        <Drawer.Screen name="DummyHome" component={PlaceHome} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

[image]

Hope it helps